# Can we write a SINGLE query for retrieving PROPERTIES from TWO CLASSES in WMIC?

Tags: windows, wmi, windows-server-2003, wmic

I want to retrieve the data from multiple classes in single query in WMIC.
I know that it wont be possible in WMI. But somewhere i feel it can be possible in wmic.
also i am able to retrieve and push multiple classes data in single html file by **output** and **append** commands in **WMIC** but **i want output on WMIC console itself**.

For example:- **caption** is a common property in **Win32_Operatingsystem** and **Win32_BIOS class**.
so i need single query to retrieve CAPTION property and its Value, of above two classes and again it should be in **WMIC console itself**.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you the specific WMIC query, but I think the approach would be to enumerate a common superclass of the two classes (CIM_ManagedSystemElement ?) and then filter the class names down to only those you want.

Andy